# Installing pyinstaller error: raise backend unavailable

Tags: python, macos, pip, pyinstaller

```
$ pip install pyinstaller

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.

Collecting pyinstaller

  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/32/0e0de593f129bf1d1e77eed562496d154ef4460fd5cecfd78612ef39a0cc/PyInstaller-3.4.tar.gz

  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 315, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 131, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 294, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 242, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 349, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 149, in prep_for_dist
    reqs = self.req.pep517_backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 71, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    'config_settings': config_settings
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 162, in _call_hook
    raise BackendUnavailable
BackendUnavailable
```

This happens when I try installing pyinstaller (on MacOS Mojave) and searching I can't find anything on the error.

Strangely, if I try installing on my personal user account on the Mac (both are admin) it works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need python 3

Comment: @LeonidMew I have python 3, pyinstaller is a pythin 2 package though?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. [This seems to be the bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6164) but it isn't fixed yet.